# $S^1$ a p-local complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $p$ be a prime. Is $S^1$ a p-local CW-complex? Meaning, for any reduced homology  theory $\overline{E}_*$, do we have $\overline{E}_*(S^1)=\overline{E}_*(S^1) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$?

Another question: If $\overline{H}_*(X, \mathbb{Z})=0$ then is $X$ $p$-local?

(Apologies if these questions indicate I am very confused about things).

Comment: What about the usual reduced homology? $H_*(S^1)\simeq\Bbb Z[1]$ is a copy of the integers in degree $1$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Oh, you are right, that shows $S^1$ is not p-local.